# Black screen error when using Flutter SvgPicture

Tags: flutter, svg, flutter-web

When using the code below, my SvgPicture widget, which I wrapped with container, appears black. I'm sure the data from the API is correct.

```
Container(
                              height: 100,
                              width: 100,
                              child: SvgPicture.network(
                                _controller._cargoDocumentPrint.value!.orderCargo![0].cargoPlatform!.platformLogo!,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
```

Comment: Provide error log in your question

Comment: Have you tried it with an SVG you are certain to work? For example: https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg

Comment: @StefanGaller hi, I am trying to write a web project. It worked on the emulator but still doesn't work on the web.

Comment: @MojtabaGhiasi no error is returned

Comment: @atasumt flutter_svg plugin has no support for web

Comment: @MojtabaGhiasi what to do instead?

Comment: Try Image.network for the web it maybe works for SVG images